# How to set an enviromental variable to indicate test environment in Cypress

Tags: automated-testing, cypress

I need to include in my test scenarios a way to determine which environment they are being executed in.
We have BVT (build verification test) and a UAT (user Acceptance Test) environments.
Within our solution we have environment.ts files for each of our environments and I have access to the files:

- environment.bvt.ts
- environment.uat.ts
- environment.ts

My question is:

- How do I alter my test so that when it runs in a particular environment (through a Bamboo CI build)

Example of my login test is below

```
describe('Environment', function (){
    it('Environment selection', function (){
        cy.visit('https://bvt-riskassessment.lmkcloud.net')
        cy.get('span.mat-button-wrapper').contains('Log In').click()
        }
    )
})
```

Answer (score 1):

My colleague and I have worked out how to do this.

I had to create a Cypress.env.json which contains a property and value that I want to use.
Then in my test I replace the

`cy.visit('https://bvt-riskassessment.lmkcloud.net')`

with

`cy.visit(Cypress.env("riskApp"))`

Then in the bamboo build process we can specify which environment to call by using something along the lines of:

```
cypress run --env host=kevin.dev.local,api_server=http://localhost:8888/api/v1
```